# Firebase Google Analytics 4 - "exception" vs. "app_exception"

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

Is it possible to manually track exceptions using Firebase GA4 Analytics?

I have been checking few documents that refers to two different events:

1. [app_exception](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069)
2. [exception](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/exceptions#implementation)

So... what should I do? Are both ways correct?

```
analytics.logEvent("exception", {
  description: error.message ?? "Unexpected error.",
  fatal: false,
});
```

VS

```
analytics.logEvent("app_exception", {
  description: error.message ?? "Unexpected error.",
  fatal: false,
});
```